# How to align multiple edges to another by moving only their upper vertices

Tags: edges

I have a rather complicated case ... at least for me.
As you can see here

[image]

I have multiple edges with lower vertex placed on the XY plane. Upper vertices all have different positions and height so all edges have different orientation. I need to align the orientation of all edges to the white one - the active one - without changing the height of their upper vertices and the position of their lower vertices.

The only idea I have is to use the trick to make a vertex coplanar with another of a face. In my case I could use the active edge - the orientation reference - as axis of rotation and the lower vertex of each edge as snap vertex to rotate and align the upper one .... But I have to do it 26 times .......
Since I have a case where I have to do the same thing on more than 50 edges ... does anyone have a simpler idea? Thanks

Comment: try positioning the 3D cursor to the upper vertex of the white one and then set the transform to 3d cursor.
Then select all the other upper vertex other than white one and scale them to 0 in respective axis (x or y).
repeating the process to bottom vertices will complete it!

Comment: @Nand27 that does not preserve the vertex height.

Comment: I would use a script to get the ratios of X and Y to Z on the white edge, and then use those ratios to calculate the new positions of the other vertices.